# Get location in Zopim Chat

Tags: location, zopim

I want to configure my Zopim Live Chat as it follows. I want to configure the chat so some agents can take care for some people in one location and other agents to take care of the other people.

An example, I want some agents to take care of people near NY and other agents take care of people near Boston. How could I achieve that?

In the dashboard Zopim, provides the IP and location but I would like to get these parameters inside the code. I've searched the API but found nothing.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recognize the physical address of the IP addresses first and for this you need a GeoIP database, which links IP address to physical address.

Probably what you need is to build a call to the API of https://freegeoip.net/ and use that result inside the Zopim Live Chat.

You then add every Boston-area visitor to a department called "Boston" and so on and in the backend assign agents to specific departments.